# It is possible to retrieve specific part from a string variable in html?

Tags: html, string, variables, specifications

I have set names to a variable, but i want part of the name.

var data = fullName
and lets say the full name 1 is VAN7324 high expense and full name 2 is 632-123A blog and i want to take out the name VAN7324 from the full name 1 and 632-123A from full name 2.

so the end result would be

name = VAN7324
name = 632-123A
is there anyways i can do this?

Comment: I think you mean JavaScript variable? (Judging from the `var`s you mention). You mention that the names are never the same, so, if its JavaScript I assume you are getting them from an input? Or, if it's PHP/some other server-side code, are you getting them from a database?

Comment: This is actually a big commerce site that i been working on, there is this form on the back end that you can input variable such as VAN7324 and 632-123A. i need a way to output these variables. it so happen that these variables are part of the full name, so i need to take section of the name and out put it.

Comment: and yes i'm, geting them from a database, the variable is "%%GLOBAL_BrandName%%". the example of the whole name would be "VAN7324 high expense" and "632-123A blog " i need a way to take the first part of the name and out put it some where

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP

```
<?php
    $fullName1 = "VAN7324 high expense";
    $fullName2 = "632-123A blog";
    $fullName1 = explode(" ", $fullName1);
    $fullName2 = explode(" ", $fullName2);
    echo $fullName1[0];
    echo $fullName2[0];
?>
```

In the case it was a variable entered, for simplicity we will assume via post

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $name = explode(" ", $name);
    echo $name[0];
?>
```

This will output everything up to a space.

Comment: problem is that "VAN7324 high expense" and "632-123A blog" is a result enter by someone, meaning it is never the same name,

Comment: See edit: This should be a 'catch-all' by outputting everything up until a space.